# Listing tables from imported database in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to display the tables from the database that I have imported into the PostgreSQL database. I tried using \d but it shows no relations found.

The size of the database is around 2 GB.
Is there any other option to list the tables in the database?

Here is the set of statements I executed to import the database  and to list the tables in the database

```
postgres=# create database projects;  
CREATE DATABASE  
postgres=# \c projects;  
You are now connected to database "projects" as user "postgres".  
projects=# psql -d projects -u postgres -f demo.sql  
projects-# \c projects;  
You are now connected to database "projects" as user "postgres".  
projects-# \d  
No relations found.  
projects-#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`psql` is a command line program, **not** a SQL command.

Do not enter it at the `psql` prompt.

If you properly end every statement with a `;` the line `psql -d projects -u postgres -f demo.sql` would have given you an error right away.

To run a script from inside `psql` use `\i demo.sql`